# mongoose update nested value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some nested properties on my mogoose schema like this:

```js
const userSchemaValues = {
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Username required'],
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Password required'],
        trim: true,
        minlength: 8
    },
  
 ...
  
    prop: {
        prop_1: String,
        prop_2: String
    }
};
```

```js
valuesToUpdate.prop = _.pick(req.body, 'prop_1', 'prop_2');
 log.debug(JSON.stringify(valuesToUpdate));

 User.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: valuesToUpdate})
  .then((data) => {
   return res.json({message: data});
  })
  .catch(err => {
   log.error(err);
   return next({message: 'Error updating User.'});
  });
```

But when I do `User.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: valuesToUpdate})` on an User with prop_1 and _2 set with an object like this (`{"prop":{"prop_1": "somevalue"}`), it is not looking for what is in prop, it just overwrites it. How can I circumvent this?

Comment: Can you write complete query here?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Your find needs to include the property to update. Also the update statement needs the [Positional Update Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) Change it to (outta my head):</s>

```
valuesToUpdate.prop = _.pick(req.body, 'prop_1', 'prop_2');
    log.debug(JSON.stringify(valuesToUpdate));

    User.update({$and : [{_id: req.params.id}, {prop.prop1 : "%oldvalue%"}]}, {$set: { "prop.$.prop1" : "%newvalue""}})
        .then((data) => {
            return res.json({message: data});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            log.error(err);
            return next({message: 'Error updating User.'});
        });
```

Note that the positional update only updates the FIRST occurrence!

UPDATE: After rereading your question i saw that the props is not an array... My bad sorry.
Luckily this makes it much easier :)

You do not require the field to be present in the find
for the set : { $set : { "prop.prop1" : "newvalue" }
Also the positional update is not required because it's not an Array.

This makes the following:

```
valuesToUpdate.prop = _.pick(req.body, 'prop_1', 'prop_2');
log.debug(JSON.stringify(valuesToUpdate));

User.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: { "prop.prop1" : "%newvalue%"}})
    .then((data) => {
        return res.json({message: data});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        log.error(err);
        return next({message: 'Error updating User.'});
    });
```

UPDATE2: More information about the update statements.

Because of the comment's i'll clarify the update commands.
When you want to update a field in you document you use the [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) command.
This updates one or more fields.
When you want to update multiple field you can do it with the command like:

```
$set : { "prop.prop1" : "newvalueforprop1", "prop.prop2" : "newvalueforprop2"} }
```

BUT when you use the command above and specify one one field it generates a command like:

```
$set : { "prop.prop1" : "newvalueforprop1", "prop.prop2" : null} }
```

This is all about how you create the update command. When you don't know if it's 1 or 2 properties you need to update your code so it generate a command dynamically.
But another thing you could do is let mongoose handle the update.

Use something like:

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(err)
        }
        else {
            //you should to some checking if the supplied value is present (!= undefined) and if it differs from the currently stored one
            user.prop.prop1 = "your value";
            user.prop.prop1 = "2nd value"

            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    handleError(err)
                }
                else {
                    res.json(user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Should I do this {prop.$.prop_1: "%oldvalue%"} for every value I got?
I ask because this is in a patch route and I do not know which values will be send to update.

Comment: Sorry i was updating my answer ;-), i placed it outta my head

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this query syntax. But my IDE complains about {$set: { "prop.$" : "%newvalue"}}. For the prop. it expects a ":" and after the $ it expect an ";" ?

Comment: I updated my answer after rereading your question, i was thinking props was an array (a default in my head ;-)) so i updated. Let me know if it's ok

Comment: In fact this is what I found, searching for a solution and as you can see, I already tried it without success.
I mean I tried $set and my valuesToUpdate object is like your { "prop.prop1" : "%newvalue%"}, isn't it?

Comment: Oh no, it isn't.  So I'd split it up like 
{$set: { "prop.prop1" : valuesToUpdate.prop.prop1, "prop.prop2" : "valuesToUpdate.prop.prop2"}} ?

Comment: For updating both you Would need: { $set : { "prop.prop1" : "newvalueforprop1" } and { $set : { "prop.prop2" : "newvalueforprop2" }.

Comment: Like this?
User.update(
  {_id: req.params.id},
  {$set: {"prop.prop1": valuesToUpdate.prop1}},
  {$set: {"prop.prop2": valuesToUpdate.prop2}}
 ).then((data) => { ... 
? Because this is not working. Only prop1 gets updated, if there is no prop1, prop2 gets updated neither but prop1 gets null.

Comment: You can do it in one command:  $set : { "prop.prop1" : "newvalueforprop1", "prop.prop2" : "newvalueforprop2"} }.

Comment: This does not work...:/   When I use it like that, every time I send either prop1 or prop2, the other value gets NULL in the db...

Comment: I updates my answer to clarify the $set update command, also i added a .save option so mongoose handles the update. Hope it's clear for you so you can get it to work and accept the answer.